Computing homology of smash product $\mathbb{RP}^2\wedge\mathbb{RP}^2$
What is the easiest way to compute the homology of $\mathbb{RP}^2\wedge\mathbb{RP}^2$?
I heard there is a Künneth formula for smash products with reduced homology but could not find it online.
If it were $$\tilde{H}_k(\mathbb{RP}^2\wedge\mathbb{RP}^2, \mathbb{Z}) = \big(\bigoplus_{p+q=k}\tilde{H}_p(\mathbb{RP}^2, \mathbb{Z})\otimes \tilde{H}_q(\mathbb{RP}^2, \mathbb{Z})\big)\oplus \big(\bigoplus_{p+q=k-1}Tor_1^{\mathbb{Z}}(\tilde{H}_p(\mathbb{RP}^2, \mathbb{Z}), \tilde{H}_q(\mathbb{RP}^2, \mathbb{Z}))\big)$$, then from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%BCnneth_theorem

and so instead of 
we'd get $0, 0, \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Is this the correct answer?

Your conjectured Künneth formula is correct (you can find it on page 235 of Spanier's Algebraic Topology, albeit with not-quite-modern notation), and therefore your calculation is also correct (assuming that those are supposed to be the reduced groups, for obviously $H_0(\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^2 \wedge \mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^2) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.) You can also verify this by noting that the inclusion map $\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^2 \vee \mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^2 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^2 \times \mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^2$ induces an isomorphism on $H_1({{-}})$ and then compute $\tilde{H}_*(\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^2 \wedge \mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^2) \cong H_*(\mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^2 \times \mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^2, \mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^2 \vee \mathbb{R}\mathrm{P}^2)$ from the long exact sequence of that pair.
As for "what's the easiest way to do this computation," I'm pretty sure it doesn't get any more straightforward than with the Künneth formula :)
